# .green .progress .inner .water { top: 25%; } meaning?

Tags: css, sass

Here is a CodePen of a Progress Bar Liquid Bubble.

https://codepen.io/junebug12851/pen/mJZNqN

When I view its compiled CSS code, There are three pieces of code which I can't figure out what they are doing...

Here you go:

```
.green .progress .inner .water {
  top: 25%;
}


.red .progress .inner .water {
  top: 75%;
}


.orange .progress .inner .water {
  top: 50%;
}
```

Any Idea on this is extremely appreciated...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I got at a glance:

The jQuery is changing the parent class (the color) of .progress, which is the parent of .inner, which is the parent of .water based on the value you put in the percentage box (an input field). This way, .water can have it's individual styles, but you can change the color based on a parent class. So, for example, .water with a parent (or, great grandparent) of .green will have a green background.

The value of the property "top" is the highest point in the liquid, how close or far it is from the top. This is merely a starting point. It looks like jQuery alters the actual values. For example, if the circle is 400px tall, and a child element is absolutely positioned at top: 50%, the top of the child element will be positioned at 200px below the top of the parent. This is great for scalability. If you wanted the circle to be 200px on a mobile device, just change the size of the parents and the relative units scale accordingly.

This is deceptive for a number of reasons. First of all, they aren't styled in order. Secondly, from a human-readable standpoint, it seems like it would make more sense to use bottom instead of top and switch the values of red and green. Depending on how they've styled the rest of it and how the jQuery functions, that could break the design. Finally, the colors don't change at the same percentages. The colors change at 33-34 and 66-67. It looks like the top of the liquid sitting around 25% from the top at 67, and 75% from the top at 34.